# System.FormatException: p0 : Wa - Input string was not in a correct format. jqGrid error filteredQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, filter, toolbar

I'm in the process of following an example by Oleg that uses the filterToolbar in jqGrid to perform a server side search/filter.  The error is being thrown at the filteredQuery.Count() line when searching for the Name, but appears to be related to the FormatMapping.  I do not get the error when I do an "eq" - equal search, but do when doing the "cn" - contains search.  It's almost like there's an issue with the format string, but this exact code works fine in the example code it is taken from.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!!

```
public JsonResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters)
    {
        var context = new NonTaxContext();
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        var set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Team>();

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Filters f = (!_search || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters)) ? null : serializer.Deserialize<Filters>(filters);

        ObjectQuery<Team> filteredQuery =
        (f == null ? (ObjectQuery<Team>)set : f.FilterObjectSet((ObjectQuery<Team>)set));

        filteredQuery.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; // we don't want to update the data

        var totalRecords = filteredQuery.Count();

        var pagedQuery = filteredQuery.Skip("it." + sidx + " " + sord, "@skip",
                                            new ObjectParameter("skip", (page - 1) * rows))
                                     .Top("@limit", new ObjectParameter("limit", rows));

        // to be able to use ToString() below which does NOT exist in the LINQ to Entity
        var queryDetails = (from item in pagedQuery
                            select new { item.TeamId, item.Code, item.Name }).ToList();

        return Json(new
        {
            total = (totalRecords + rows - 1) / rows,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (from item in queryDetails
                    select new[] {
                                    item.TeamId.ToString(),
                                    item.Code,
                                    item.Name
                                }).ToList()
        });
    }

private static readonly string[] FormatMapping = {
        "(it.{0} = @p{1})",                 // "eq" - equal
        "(it.{0} <> @p{1})",                // "ne" - not equal
        "(it.{0} < @p{1})",                 // "lt" - less than
        "(it.{0} <= @p{1})",                // "le" - less than or equal to
        "(it.{0} > @p{1})",                 // "gt" - greater than
        "(it.{0} >= @p{1})",                // "ge" - greater than or equal to
        "(it.{0} LIKE (@p{1}+'%'))",        // "bw" - begins with
        "(it.{0} NOT LIKE (@p{1}+'%'))",    // "bn" - does not begin with
        "(it.{0} LIKE ('%'+@p{1}))",        // "ew" - ends with
        "(it.{0} NOT LIKE ('%'+@p{1}))",    // "en" - does not end with
        "(it.{0} LIKE ('%'+@p{1}+'%'))",    // "cn" - contains
        "(it.{0} NOT LIKE ('%'+@p{1}+'%'))" //" nc" - does not contain
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What technology stack are you using? I personally had to modify that example as I couldn't use the "LIKE" keyword as that was translating with Linq/Entity Frameworks and had to swap my `"cn"` over to

```
 "(it.{0}.ToLower().Contains(@{1}.ToLower()))",// "cn" - contains
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply.  I've very new to all of this, so not sure what technology stack I'm using.  I'm trying to use Entity Framework Code First if that helps.  Just tried you answer and now I'm getting "'toLower' is not a member of type 'Edm.String' in the currently loaded schemas."  Getting closer I can feel it.

Comment: I mean by technology stack, as in C#, SQL/MySQL, etc. Depending on what you are using for Entity Frameworks, and then what you are using for a Database you might have to change that line. I might actually be `ToLower(),` I'll edit my answer with the `t` capitalized.

Comment: Mark, I'm using VS 2012, C#, SQL Server Compact Edition.  After trying again I was still getting the same error...even with the t capitalized.  I took a shot in the dark and switched my connection string over to our SQL Server here at work.  Everything worked perfectly after that.  Not sure what the difference is between SQL Server Compact Edition and SQL Server with regards to these queries, but this seemed to get me past the issue.

Comment: I'm glad... it might just be in the way Entity Framework is going to do the translation for the DB.  If you wanted to dig into it you could examine the SQL that it was generating, but like I mentioned I had to change it over for my use of MySQL.  I hope this helped and if so please mark as the correct answer.